# Problems with extracting a date in Java with a regular expression

Tags: java, regex

For a certain API I am getting dates in a `/Date(1323312018479-0700)/` format.  For some reason the regex that I am using does not result in any matches.

Any ideas?

BTW: I am not taking into account the timezone right now.

```
public static Date parseApiDate(String rawDate) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([0-9]+)-([0-9]+)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher m = p.matcher(rawDate);

    Log.d("DATE CONVERSION: Raw", rawDate);
    if (m.matches()) {
        String utc = m.group(1);
        int milliSeconds = Integer.parseInt(utc);
        Date date = new Date(milliSeconds);

        Log.d("DATE CONVERSION: milliseconds", utc);
        Log.d("DATE CONVERSION: Converted", date.toGMTString());

        return date;
    } else {    
        return new Date(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: If it's of the same format always, you can use string parsing, which would be better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `m.find()` instead of `m.matches()`. Then you'd need `Long.parseLong()`

Generally, you should parse dates with `DateFormat` (`SimpleDateFormat`), but in this case it can't cope. The pattern `SZ` fails, perhaps because it is not sure where the timezone starts (although it should be able to do that)

Comment: I got hung up on the regex and missed the the fact that I was trying to convert a long to an int, which was the sole cause.

Answer (score 0):

Try it with

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*?([0-9]+)-([0-9]+).*?", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
```

Comment: @chris - You need to combine this answer with what Bozho mentioned about using *Long*.

Comment: The regex actually works fine without the addition lazy expression addition.  The exception that was being thrown wasn't printing the stacktrace which is why I kept thinking that it was the problem.